# Results of SAT on the Qiskit simulator

Tags: qiskit, measurement, simulation

I computed SAT formula with the Grover search algorithm on the Qiskit simulator with default parameters, but I don't understand why the incorrect solutions don't have a probability of 0?

The SAT formula is $(x_1 \vee x_2) \wedge (x_2 \vee x_3)$.

[image: result]

Comment: Hi! What was the sat formula you were using?

Comment: Sorry @met927 , the formula is :  _(x1 v x2) ^ (x2 v x3)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the algorithm works well. Your formula returns zero for inputs 000, 001 and 100. Those values have very low probability in comparison with others states in histogram you provided. Since there is some level of noise, the probabilities are not zero for 000, 001 and 100.

Note that even the simulator on IBM Q generates some *noise* because of finite precision of the simulator.

**Overall, there is no mistake.**

Comment: I read on [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/how-to-run-the-qiskit-aer-simulator-without-noise) that the qasm simulator has no noise by default ?

Comment: @julienrodriguez: Sorry for my inaccuracy, but the result is the same. That is the simulator does not corespond with theory 1:1.

Comment: @julienrodriguez: I fixed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @Martin :)